# android listview getView() method does not make the same updates as onListItemClick() method for background color

Tags: android, background-color, android-listview

I am attempting to update the background color of a list item when it is selected and keep the changes even if the view changes.
My update works as expected when I click on the item but can not get it to maintain the changes if I leave the view.  I thought that 
making the same update in the getView () method would give me what I needed but it doesn't seem to work.  Any suggestions?

```
       public class MyScaAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    public MyScaAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
            String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    }
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

                if (convertView == null & position == selectedPos) {
                    v.setSelected(true);
                    v.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.background_light);
                }        
                return v;
             }  
         }

    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

       v.setSelected(true);
       v.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.background_light);  


        selectedPos = position;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a global reference to the view so that you can set your background color in the `onResume()` method.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried it but it did not work.  Also, I confirmed in debug that I had the same view id as onListItemClick.

Comment: Can you reference it by `selectedPos`?

Comment: Yes, I can store both selectedPos and the view id in the onListItemClick method and they are displayed correctly during the onResume method.  It actually executes the code but it does not change the listView.